# Edit data from gridview on bootstap modal

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem when I edit data select from grid view and update on bootstrap modal.

ASPX:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvcat" CssClass="table table-bordered font-13" Width="500px" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' OnClick="lnkView_Click"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  causesvalidation="false">View</asp:LinkButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to do? What does it currently do? Can you please edit the question with more information, such as any error messages, what you've tried, or what happens when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

aspx body:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">
                Add New Metal Group</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
              <asp:HiddenField ID="hfID" runat="server" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group-sm">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Category Name" type="text" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Description" type="text" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                   <%-- <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorDescription" CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This field is Required !" ControlToValidate="txtDescription"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group-sm">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn btn-sm" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnClear" CssClass="btn btn-sm" runat="server" OnClick="btnClear_Click" Text="Clear" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TFRWebAppConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("CategoryCreateOrUpdate", sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", (hfID.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(hfID.Value)));
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDescription.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            gvcat.DataBind();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
 protected void lnkView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TFRWebAppConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblCategory WHERE ID = @ID", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID); // this line was mising in your code
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dtcategory = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dtcategory);
                con.Close();
                hfID.Value = ID.ToString();
                txtName.Text = dtcategory.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
                txtDescription.Text = dtcategory.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
            }

        }
    }

}
```